# Gitlab: project not found when trying to get pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to get pipelines of a project using this `GET` request:

```
https://my-company.com/api/v4/projects/2080/pipelines
```

The response is:

```
{
    "message": "404 Project Not Found"
}
```

Although the project exists and I definitely use the correct project id.
We use `GitLab Enterprise Edition 11.9.0-ee`. Any hints?

EDIT:
Project id is taken from this place:
[image]

Comment: could you test to get single project detail using `GET https://my-company.com/api/v4/projects/2080` ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster I get same response (not found)

Comment: And searching with Search API `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/search?scope=projects&search=PROJECTNAME` ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster response code 200, but the response body is empty array

Comment: could you add to your question a print screen of your project Name with Project ID below (check in `Project Overview` > `Details` ) ?

Comment: Try checking the url in your browser, first login to company gitlab and go to project page, then paste in other tab the request `https://my-company.com/api/v4/projects/2080/pipelines`. If it displays correctly then it must be missing token/credentials in your request.

Comment: @makozaki but shouldn't I get '401 unauthorized' in this case?

Comment: I get `404 Project Not Found` when I'm not logged in, and full data when I'm logged in. The same for curl request.

Comment: Did you select `api` scope when you created  your access token ? Are you member of the project ? Which are you rights ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster actually I'm the owner.

Comment: @makozaki you were right. I was using a technical user's token. and this user wasn't part of the project. I added him to the project group and it worked. 
Thanks everyone.